# What options are available for high-throughput isolation and identification of microbes from soil?

Tags: microbiology, dna-isolation, soil

I have a lot of experience with isolating individual colonies / species / organisms from the environment and then sequencing them for identification, but the process is slow and cumbersome.

My goal is to build an organism library so actually having the individual isolates is desired. The metagenomic approaches are great for screening a pool of organisms for something I'm looking for, but I still have to separate it out if I want to keep it.

I currently create soil dilutions, plate them, isolate colonies early on to create axenic cultures and then DNA barcode the microbes. This process is time-consuming and often biased towards faster growing microbes.

Are there any high-throughput methods of isolating and identifying microbes (mainly fungi and bacilli) from a mixed-substrate like soil?

A literature search on this subject doesn't reveal many options that are currently accessible. I'm seeing some research on microfluidic devices that may help, but I'm not aware of any microfluidic platforms that are available to consumers.

Aside from this technique and microfluidic techniques (not currently available to my knowledge), are there any other techniques to consider to improve throughput?

Comment: Can you please provide more detail and focus your question a bit more narrowly as this kind of open ended question isn't a good fit for this site. (e.g. Do you really need to isolate and why?) ——— If I search for "soil genomics" the top two hits are articles from Nature Reviews Microbiology titled ["Soil genomics"](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrmicro2119-c1) and ["The metagenomics of soil"](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrmicro1160). Have you read these and looked for more recent reviews and articles that reference them? Does this not allow you to find answers?

Comment: The question is very specific: what high-throughput methods are available for isolating and identifying microbes like fungi and bacteria? I don't know how to make it more specific than that. I stated what I want to do which is separate (isolate) the microbes and identify them (their species). I would like to know what high-throughput methods are available. The reason why has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Have you looked into metagenome-assembled genomes? E.g. don't bother with isolation, just process everything together and rely on data analysis to pull the different genomes apart. This can be done with or without extra lab steps that add additional info (I once worked at a company that did this as a service: https://phasegenomics.com/products/proximeta/, so **conflict of interest** there). This is pretty routine at this point. You can also do it on standard shotgun metagenomes (e.g. https://www.nature.com/articles/s41587-020-00777-4), it's just slightly messier.

Comment: I'm building an organism library so actually having the individual isolates is desired. The metagenomic approaches are great for screening a pool of organisms for something I'm looking for, but I still have to separate it out if I want to keep it.

Comment: Do you now see why I suggested you tell us why you want to do this? SE sites get many questions that fall into a trap known as the [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which means it is almost always a good idea to include "why" information in your questions. It is also best to include such information in the text rather than responding in comments — this is because comments are ephemeral and often overlooked. Finally edits should be incorporated directly into the text and not labeled — changes are tracked by the site anyways.

Comment: If your goal is just to get a lot of unique isolates, picking colonies from agar plates is pretty much a necessary evil. Colony picker robots can automate that part of the process. One potentially faster alternative to DNA barcoding is whole cell MALDI-TOF-MS, which can dereplicate isolates and potentially ID some of them with medium-ish throughput. I can pick and screen about 1000 colonies in a day without automation. Most of the ID libraries are geared for pathogen ID, so you'd probably end up sequencing still. But you can add your own spectra as your collection grows.

Comment: I've looked into MALDI-TOF but it seems like there are two big issues: one is that even if there is a strain of interest found in the results, I still need to go through the process of plating and isolating it and hoping I can distinguish it morphologically from the rest. The other is price. I'm an indie scientist and can't spend $20K on a machine like that. Curious to hear your thoughts on it though. Appreciate the info for sure.

Comment: @tyersome I can see your perspective clearly, yes. Can you understand how I might also see from my perspective that the question was clear? I don't think either side is all right or wrong. Clearly, SE admins/users/mods are trying their best to deal with an onslaught of low-quality questions. But as a long-time user, I am frequently met with downvotes and negative reactions for not asking a question in _just_ the right way. It's a negative experience for both of us. I don't know the solution but I'm not alone in these thoughts.

Comment: @MikeyC I'd love to pick your brain more if you'd allow for it. Is there a way I can connect with you? I'd like to learn more about how you're able to screen 1000 colonies without automation. And what does screen mean exactly? (ID, assay, isolate, etc.) Thank you kindly.

Comment: @doremi No automation in the sense of robotic colony pickers or sample prep. It takes me roughly 30 minutes to spot 96 colonies onto a disposable MALDI target chip. The raw data is a peptide mass fingerprint (PMF), from which the software can generate IDs down to the species level, but only for organisms in the database. For colonies with no ID, there are dedicated Python packages for binning spectra into groups likely to be the same species. From there you could sequence as many isolates per bin as you deem necessary to confirm the identity of that PMF-type.

Comment: @MikeyC Got it. I'm hearing many folks warn about the limitation of the databases. That's  going to be a deal breaker for me since most of my target organisms are non-pathogenic and often only recently described. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to know what you would consider "high-throughput", but it might be worth checking out the work by Kim Lewis at Northeastern University — see for example his 2020 Perspective in Cell<sup>1</sup>.

One of the tools his group uses is what they call the ichip, which allows them to grow "uncultivable" microbes<sup>2</sup>. This is done by placing the device in soil after sealing in 384 separate samples.

#### References:

1. [Lewis, K. (2020). The science of antibiotic discovery. Cell, 181(1), 29-45.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867420302336)
2. [Nichols, D., Cahoon, N., Trakhtenberg, E. M., Pham, L., Mehta, A., Belanger, A., ... & Epstein, S. (2010). Use of ichip for high-throughput in situ cultivation of “uncultivable” microbial species. Applied and environmental microbiology, 76(8), 2445-2450.](https://journals.asm.org/doi/full/10.1128/AEM.01754-09)